# Variable Content Based on Parameter in Function

Tags: php

I'd like the have the output of the html return two possible markups based on a parameter the user can set. The parameter `text_mode` will be defined by the user by adding `basic` or `advanced`.

Right now, the `$output` is set for testing to show the basic version whereby the user's string is wrapped in a `<p>`. If the `text_mode` is set to advanced, then it's not wrapped.

```
<?php
function PCHiddenTextBlock( $settings = array() ) {

//---- Get Settings ----
//The functions default settings will be merged with what's passed in.

$settingsDefault = array(
    'small_heading' => '',
    'text' => '',
    'text_mode' => 'basic', //or advanced
    'color_scheme' => 'accent4',//accent4 or accent1
    'container_id' => '',
    'container_class' => 'x_extraContent',
);

$settings = array_merge($settingsDefault, $settings);


//---- Set Variables ----
//These will allow the markup build up to be as clean as possible.


//If container_id is set, prepare the attribute
$has_container_id = strlen($settings['container_id']) > 0;
$possible_container_id_attribute = ($has_container_id) ? " id='{$settings['container_id']}'" : "";

//Color scheme variables
switch($settings['color_scheme']) {
    case 'accent1':
        $gcol_color_class = 'bg-color-accent1-C';
                $color_accent_class = 'color-accent1-8';
                $hover_color_class = 'hover-color-base-4';
        break;

    default: //accent4
        $gcol_color_class = 'bg-color-accent4-D';
                $color_accent_class = 'color-accent4-A';
                $hover_color_class = 'hover-color-base-4';
}


//---- Build Output ----
//Line by line, concatenating strings with new line and tab characters.
$output  = "\n<!-- Hidden Text Block -->";
$output .= "\n<div class='{$settings['container_class']} gcol-1 {$gcol_color_class}'{$possible_container_id_attribute}>";
$output .= "\n\t<div class='padbox-standard-content'>";
$output .= "\n\t\t<h2 class='small-heading color-accent1-9'>{$settings['small_heading']}</h2>";
$output .= "\n\t\t<p>{$settings['text']}</p>"; // basic version
$output .= "\n\t\t<a href='' class='x_extraContentClose box-close-icon {$color_accent_class} {$hover_color_class}'></a>";
$output .= "\n\t</div><!-- padbox-standard-content-->";
$output .= "\n</div><!-- Hiddent Text Block -->";

//---- Return Output ----
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a url parameter is?

Comment: @gview What does that have to do with it? He's talking about the parameters in the `$settings` array.

Comment: It's such a trivial question, it seems as if this is one of those things where someone is trying to change code they didn't write and don't understand, but I see your point.  I focused on the actual first sentence of the question.  I have a hard time understanding how someone passes in an array of settings, shows code with a switch statement in it, but doesn't know what an if then else is for.

Comment: You are correct. It's not ALL my code ;) But I was making sure I got the if/else part correct. I was over-thinking / potentially over-engineering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `if` statement:

```
if ($settings['text_mode'] == 'basic') {
    $output .= "\n\t\t<p>{$settings['text']}</p>"; // basic version
} else {
    $output .= "\n\t\t{$settings['text']}<"; // advanced version
}
```

Comment: I was over-thinking it. Thanks